# How to import javax.smartcardio in a osgi bundle when building with maven?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I'm trying to add a module to an existing osgi framework (www.ogema.org).
I have to use a library that depends on javax.smartcardio. I added the library to a local repository and that seems to work.
But when I want to start the bundle that uses the library i get the error:

```
The bundle "org.ogema.examples.securitymodule-app_1.1.1 [12]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: javax.smartcardio; version="0.0.0"
```

How can I add javax.smartcardio as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javax.smartcardio is part of the  JRE (at least in 6, not sure if it was already in 5, the spec JSR 268 is from 2006 so it could have been in J5).

It is very likely that you framework does not export this package. You can export this package from the framework by setting the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` framework property to `javax.smartcardio;version=1.0.0;jsr=268` (the JSR or version are optional but it is nice documentation).

In bndtools you could do:

```
  -runsystempackages: \
    javax.smartcardio;version=1.0.0;jsr=268
```

Answer (score 1):

It already is added as a dependency, so that's fine. The problem is that you don't have a bundle in the OSGi Framework that *exports* the `javax.smartcardio` package. For each imported package in a bundle there has to be a corresponding export of that package from another bundle.

I'm not familiar with the Smartcard API so I can't offer advice on how to find a bundle that exports it. If it is available as a plain JAR file then you may need to "wrap" it as an OSGi bundle.